# Median for 2d array with sigma clipping in Python

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy

I have a large `2D array` and I want to do `sigma clipping` then calculate the median on one of the axis.

1. Is there a way to do that in one step?
2. Is doing the sigma clipping then calculating the median for each column the only way i can do it? The sigma clipping will change the lengths of the arrays). My array is pretty large and this seems a bit inefficient (a typical array I work with will have `shape = (29000, 2000)`).

Example

```
x= random.random(9000).reshape(1000, 9)
v= []
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    y= sigmaclip(x[i], 1.5, 1.5)
    m= median(y[0])
    v.append(m)
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're using [this scipy function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.stats.sigmaclip.html)? The `sigmaclip` function is itself iterative, but the `for` loop is probably slowing you down the most (especially as you're iterating along the longest axis). You may be able to make this faster (though perhaps not simpler) using array operations, perhaps something like this:

```
top     = 1.5
bot     = 1.5
xm      = ma.masked_array(x)

while 1:
    mn  = ma.mean(xm, axis=1)
    sig = ma.std(xm, axis=1)
    mask= (((xm.T <= (mn - bot*sig)) | (xm.T >= (mn + top*sig)))).T

    if (mask == xm.mask).all():
        break
    xm.mask     = mask

med     = ma.median(xm, axis = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks @jtrayford. I was just looking for something more compact. My for loop took a few seconds to run for a (1600, 29000) array so i guess i will stick to it.

Comment: OK, this method doesn't offer much speed up if the for loop is iterating over the minor axis. It's all probably moot if it's so quick to run anyway!